# Access tables are locked post SSMA migration

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

I migrated a mdb files with quite a  few tables. Post migration I could see few tables have got migrated but are locked in Access database. Could someone tell how to unlock the table? or what is causing only a few tables to get locked and not all?

Since my application contacts the mdb tables, it throws an error saying - "could not open table or is in read only".

Comment: Do all your SQL tables have a primary key defined? If not, try it out

Comment: it really helped..Its a SSMA limitation(migration tool) limitation..
"If a table without a unique index is upsized, it will be uneditable after the upsizing"

Comment: No problem, please tick the question as answered :)